# Finding a Good Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to link the index page from my movies model to the index page of my random generator model. I am using Ruby version 1.9.2  This is what the top few lines of the movie index view looks like:

This is the top two lines of my index view

```
%h1 Topical Memory System

= link_to "View Random Generators", randomgenerator_path
```

and this is what my routes file looks like:

```
Rottenpotatoes::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  resources :randomgenerators
  # map '/' to be a redirect to '/movies'
  root :to => redirect('/movies')
end
```

When I try to run the app on WEBrick, it throws an exception at those top lines and says the the route for `{:action => "show", 
:controller => "randomgenerators" }` does not exist when rake routes says it does. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label says "view random generators".  That sounds to me like a list of all the generators, in which case your link should actually be:

```
= link_to "View Random Generators", randomgenerators_path
```

Notice above that I made randgenerators plural.  If you actually meant to go to the  show action, than you need to provide an :id for which randomgenerator it is that you want to see:

```
= link_to "View Random Generators", randomgenerator_path(whatever the id is you're trying to get)
```